# Symfony Doctrine: records added to table unexpectedly

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In my Symfony code I've used Doctrine.
In an Entity ( AppBundle\Entity\Core\User ) I defined a column *foodTypes*, which is associated with another Entity (AppBundle\Entity\FoodRecording\FoodType).
I've defined an Many-to-Many relationship between *User* and *FoodType*, with a linking table *foodrecording_user*, joining *User.username* and *FoodType.foodtype_code*.
The code is shown below.

```
// Entity\Core\User
namespace AppBundle\Entity\Core;
......
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
......
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\FoodRecording\FoodType")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="foodrecording_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="username", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="foodtype_code", referencedColumnName="code", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *      )
 */
private $foodTypes;
```

As expected, I can fetch foodTypes of a certain user, and everything seems like good, until I occasionally found out that ...

everytime I run the application, it seems like that the program unexpectedly adds **new records** in the table *foodrecording_user*, for instance, if the original contents in this table are:

```
username    foodtype_code
30001180    1020
30001180    1660
30001180    320
30001270    1660
30001270    580
```

Then, after running the application with the user named 30001180, the contents will turn to be something like:

```
username    foodtype_code
30001180    1020
30001180    1660
30001180    320
30001270    1660
30001270    580
112         1020
112         1660
112         320
```

Here the 112 is the ID (primary key) of the user (with username 30001180).
That means, the program seems to duplicate the records of the user, just replacing the username (30001180) with the ID (112).

I'm sure I did not write any code to *duplicate* the records in the database - I've just read out them (*Select*) without any writing operations like *Insert* or *Update*.

Could anyone tell me, why this happened? I am so confused!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I mean the data had to get there in the 1st place, right? How did it get there? You don't have *any* `persist`/`flush` calls anywhere? No `CASCADE` definitions in your entities?

Comment: Seems to me like having cascade directives anywhere in the code. So if you don't call doctrine operations explicit thats the only logic explanation to me ...

Comment: @Jim: thanks! I changed *cascade* into *restrict* and then no more *unexpected records* will be added to the table automatically. But could you  explain why?

Comment: I don't know about a restrict option for doctrine cascade directive. What i meant is, that if you have cascade directives anywhere in your code it could happen that if one collection get saved another collection also get saved without calling explicit save operation on that collection. Just removing cascade operations haphazardly may not be the right solution as they will cause problems on other places. Just try to find the reason WHY it gets called. If its not meaningful, consider to remove.